# Номер первого максимального нечетного числа из данного набора

Tags: c++builder

Дано целое число N и набор из N целых чисел. Найти номер первого максимального нечетного числа из данного набора. Если нечетные числа в наборе отсутствуют, то вывести 0.

Программа:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *Rus(const char *text);

void main()
{
    int a[10];
    int i, n, max;
    cout << Rus(" Введите n: ");
    cin >> n;
    randomize();
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 50;
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    max = a[0];
    for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        if ((a[i] > max) && (a[i] % 2 != 0))
            max = a[i];
    }
    {
        if ((max == a[0]) && (a[0] % 2 != 0) || (max != a[0]))
            cout << "  " << Rus("искомый элемент= ") << max;
        else
            cout << "  " << Rus(" таких элементов нет ");
    }

    getch();
}

char bufRus[256];
char *Rus(const char *text)
{
    CharToOem(text, bufRus);
    return bufRus;
}
```

Программа неправильно считает. Как правильно записать условия?

Comment: @IvAn, столько однотипных заданий в такой срок ... за одногрупников лабы сдаете ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *Rus(const char *text);

void main()
{
    int a[10];
    int i, n, max;
    cout << Rus("Введите n: ");
    cin >> n;
    randomize();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 50;
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    max = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if ((a[i] > a[max]) && (a[i] % 2 == 1))
            max = i;
    }
    if(a[max]%2==1) cout << "  " << Rus("Результат: ") << max+1;
        else cout << "  " << Rus("Результат: ") << 0;

    getch();
}

char bufRus[256];
char *Rus(const char *text)
{
    CharToOem(text, bufRus);
    return bufRus;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, этот вариант больше нравится

Comment: а условие ,что если нет нечетных цисел, то вывсти 0?

Comment: А теперь все понял, сам разобрался, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм прост: последовательно ищем нечетное значение, превышающее последнее сохраненное.

```
int a[] = {1, 3, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4, 9};
int n = 0, v = INT_MIN;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
        if (a[i] % 2 == 1 && a[i] > v) {
                n = i + 1;
                v = a[i];
        }

// Нумеруем с единицы
printf("Max = %d", n);
```